# Плавный Transition в Firefox

Tags: html, css, jquery, firefox

Как сделать плавный транзишн изображения при движении мышки в Firefox, в хроме анимация происходит плавно, а в Firefox какими-то рывками. Заранее благодарен!

Реализация через Margin:

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var amountMovedX = 100 - 30 * ((e.pageX + 1) / $(document).width());
  $('div.justPhoto').css('transition', '.15s');
  $('div.justPhoto').css({
    'margin-right': '-' + amountMovedX + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.justPhoto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 90vh;
}

div.justPhoto img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="justPhoto">
  <img src="https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/girl/12-2-girl-png-hd.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Реализация через Transform:

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var amountMovedX = 100 - 30 * ((e.pageX + 1) / $(document).width());
  $('div.startScreen .me').css('transition', '.15s');
  girl.style.transform = 'translateX(' + amountMovedX + 'px)';
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.girl {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 90vh;
}

div.girl img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="girl" id="girl">
  <img src="https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/girl/12-2-girl-png-hd.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать анимацию не через margin, а через transform.

Comment: @MoloF Реализовал через Transform, однако почти такая же ситуация, изображение как-будто застревает на месте на какое-то время. Прикрепил реализацию в сниппет

Comment: на chrome полёт нормальный, на Edge полёт нормальный, но только с Transform, с margin проблемы, попробуйте так же убрать transition , он не нужен, только задержку добавляет.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var amountMovedX = 100 - 30 * ((e.pageX + 1) / $(document).width());
  girl.style.transform = 'translateX(' + amountMovedX + 'px)';
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.girl {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 90vh;
}

div.girl img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="girl" id="girl">
  <img src="https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/girl/12-2-girl-png-hd.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Нет возможности протестировать на firefox, но на Chrome/Edge/IE работает отлично.

Проблема "поддёргивания" возникает из-за **Transition**